# React native init is not working in new fresh project

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to create a fresh project with react-native 0.59.8 but is failing.

I have tried different versions of react-native so I think the problem is in yarn, node or npm versions that i'm using.

```sh
{ Error: Command failed: yarn add react-native --exact
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:653:13)
    at run (/Users/francesco/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (/Users/francesco/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at init (/Users/francesco/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/francesco/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12) }
```

My stack is:

- node: 10.15.3
- npm: 6.4.1
- yarn: 1.16.0
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: you want to initial new project or change react-native version on existing project ?

Comment: Please illustrate which command you are using to create react native app

Comment: Standard way: react-native init AppName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing yarn cache first : `yarn cache clean` . Then run 
`react-native init ProjectName`
Which OS you are using ?

Update: 
Solution: It was because react-native init was running on another file system(google drive in this case). Changing the location of `react-native init projectname` to default file system that OS is using worked.

Comment: It's failing with the same result.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Try reinstalling node then try again.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS. I'm using nvm 0.34.0 for node and i have already tried to reinstall my node version..

Comment: Is there a `yarn-error.log` file in that directory ? If so you can check that log file and one possible reason can be that there might be an internet connectivity issue. If that's the case then you can try these solutions to fix : https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3227

Comment: Yes there is!

This is the trace:

Error: ENOSYS: function not implemented, symlink '../../../parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> 'AppName/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/.bin/parser'

Comment: Are you using some other file system ? Maybe this can help https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1381 . Also try installing at other locations.

Comment: Oh thank you! I was creating in my Google Drive directory! When I created project in my file system it worked!

Comment: Awesome! I am updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use React-native 0.57 version for better stability and make sure you have node modules greater than version 10 and correct environmental variables

```
react-native init ProjectName --version react-native@0.57.8
```

Comment: It's failing with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If your `$ node -v` is below 12, update to 12 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

This version works for me as of May 2022.

`npx react-native init deeplinktest --version 0.67.4`

Answer (score -3):

try with 
    react-native init YourProjectName

Comment: you need to use it as npx react-native init <project name>